# sharing opportunities with partners

Tags: sharing, profile

Is there a way of sharing opportunities that are not closed with specific license type or profiles? I want to be able to share only closed opportunities with my partners.

Answer (score 2):

Opportunities can be shared through a partner portal using [partner licenses](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_license_types_partnerportal.htm&language=en_US). They can be read-only, create or update. They're not visible at all through a [Communities portal](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&language=en_US) unless you "mirror" them out to the portal using custom objects and triggers. That would be one way of doing what you want for your "read only" closed opportunities situation. I just finished a project of that nature using a HVCP license for a client.

Comment: Not true. Opportunities are visible through a Partner Community. While HVCP licenses do not expose Opportunities, Partner Community licenses do.

Comment: I suggest you re-read my Answer. I did not state the HVCP license provided visibility to Opportunity. The Opportunities were exposed to the HVCP portal users through a mirrored object using triggers.

Comment: I just reread your answer. Stating that "they're not visible at all through a Communities portal" is inaccurate. And mirroring through custom objects is a workaround for sharing Opportunities that is not a best-practice. I know you said that HVCP does not provide Opportunity visibility. But there are other portal licenses that you did not address.

Comment: There ARE "Partner Communities" now if that's what you mean by my statement being "inaccurate". Unless one already has Partner Portal licenses, the only new Partner "portals" allowed are "Partner Communities". SF is migrating to the Communities model for portals. One can also have a HVCP Community if they have that license. They're all simply different licenses regardless of what you call them. I'm done with this topic.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this may be what you're looking for:

```
public static void processOpportunityShares(List<Opportunity> opps)
{
    List<OpportunityShare> oppShares = new List<OpportunityShare>();
    for(Opportunity o : opps)
    {
        if(o.IsClosed)
        {
            OpportunityShare os = new OpportunityShare();
            os.OpportunityId = o.Id;
            os.OpportunityAccessLevel = 'Edit';
            // os.UserOrGroupId = id of user you wish to share this opportunity with
            oppShares.add(os);
        }
    }

    Database.SaveResult[] results = Database.insert(oppShares, false);
    for(Database.SaveResult sr : results)
    {
        if(sr.isSuccess())
        {
            system.debug('Partner Share successful');
        }
        else
        {
            Database.Error err = sr.getErrors()[0];
            if(err.getStatusCode() == StatusCode.FIELD_FILTER_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION && err.getMessage().contains('AccessLevel'))
            {
                system.debug('Partner Share successful');
            }
            else
            {
                system.debug('Partner Share unsuccessful');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Force.com Site (less ideal) or a Partner Community (ideal) to share those Opportunities with partners. This also lets you segment other things the partners can see if they are internal users, as it sounds like you have them today.